# How to change the index in a foreach loop depending on the index value

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, ifthenelse

I this example:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usepackage    {siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d}      
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    

% \usepackage{enumitem,setspace,kantlipsum}
% isometric
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},% vectores i,j,k
                    thick,line cap=round,line join=round, scale=0.7]

\def\br{1.5}  
\def\be{4}    

\def\we{17.6} 
\def\ws{4}    


\fill[canvas is yz plane at x=-\ws,gray!30] (-1.2*\ws,0)    rectangle (1.2*\ws,\we+1); 
\fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0   ,gray!15] (-\ws,-1.2*\ws) rectangle (7,1.2*\ws); 
\draw[dashed] (0,0,\be) -- (0,0,0) -- (\ws,0,0)  node[midway,sloped, above, xshift=-0.65cm] {\SI{40}{cm}};
\fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0,gray!80] (\ws,0) circle (0.25) node[black,xshift=1.25cm] {}; %
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,cyan, dashed] (\ws,0) circle (2.25) node[black,xshift=0.85cm, align=left] {Boxing\\ Zone};


\draw[fill= red!20] ($(-135:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$) --++ (0,0,-9.6)
    {[canvas is xy plane at z=\be] arc (-135:45:\br)} -- ($(45:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$);

\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=\be+9.6,fill=red!40] (0,0) circle (\br);

\foreach[count=\xi]\i in{1.5,4.2,6.9}
{%                       1.5, 1.5+2.7, 1.5+2.7+2.7
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\be+\i] 
    \draw[orange] (0,0) circle (\br);
    \fill[orange] (0,0,\be+\i) circle (1pt); 
    \coordinate   (C\xi) at (225:\br+0.2); 
    %--
    \foreach \k in {0,120,240}
    {%
      \begin{scope}[rotate=\k]  
        \draw[gray,dashed] (0,0) -- (\br,0);
        \draw[red, opacity=0.85, fill=blue!75,fill opacity=0.6,] (0.75,-0.12) rectangle (1.1,0.12);
      \end{scope}
    }
    %--
  \end{scope}
}

\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
{%
  \draw[line width=0.5mm] ($(\i:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$) -- (0,0,\we-0.15);
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,-\br,\be+9.6) --++ (0,0,-0.5); 
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (\br, 0,\be+9.6) --++ (0,0,-0.5); 
% Wall structure
\begin{scope}[shift={(-\ws,0,\we)},line width=1.5mm]
  \draw (0.5*\ws ,0,0) -- (0,0,-0.5*\ws) -- (0,0,-\ws); 
  \draw (0,-0.5*\ws,0) -- (0,0.5*\ws,0); 
  \draw (0,0,0)        -- (1.25*\ws,0,0);
 
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to change the angle \k of the sections which are plotted with:

```
    %--
    \foreach \k in {0,120,240}
    {%
      \begin{scope}[rotate=\k]  
        \draw[gray,dashed] (0,0) -- (\br,0);
        \draw[red, opacity=0.85, fill=blue!75,fill opacity=0.6,] (0.75,-0.12) rectangle (1.1,0.12);
      \end{scope}
    }
    %--
```

as a function of the foreach with index \i (\foreach[count=\xi]\i in{1.5,4.2,6.9})
For example, if the value of \i is 1.5 (the first value of the list) do nothing but if the values are 4.2 or 6.9 then the rotation given by angle \k should change to 60, 180, and 300 degrees.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. What does the value of `\i` have to do with `\k`?

Comment: @Someone `\i` is the height of the horizontal sections in the boxing bag and `\k`are the angles of the radius (the three dashed lines). What I would like is to change `\k` as a function of `\i`.

Comment: Did you mean 60, 180, 300?

Comment: `\foreach [evaluate={\kk={ifthenelse(\i<4, \k, \k+60)}}] \k in {0,120,240}     {       \begin{scope}[rotate=\kk]` will do that. If `\i` is less than 4, set `\kk` to `\k`, otherwise set it to `\k+60`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

```
\foreach [evaluate={\kk={ifthenelse(\i<4, \k, \k+60)}}] \k in {0,120,240}    
    {       
      \begin{scope}[rotate=\kk]
```

`evaluate` lets you calculate a new value based on the loop variable. So here I use `ifthenelse` to check the value of `\i`, and set the new variable `\kk` to either `\k` or `\k+60`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usepackage    {siunitx} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d}      
\usetikzlibrary{babel}   
\usetikzlibrary{calc}    

% \usepackage{enumitem,setspace,kantlipsum}
% isometric
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zy{sqrt(2/3)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},z={(0 cm,\zy cm)},% vectores i,j,k
                    thick,line cap=round,line join=round, scale=0.7]

\def\br{1.5}  
\def\be{4}    

\def\we{17.6} 
\def\ws{4}    


\fill[canvas is yz plane at x=-\ws,gray!30] (-1.2*\ws,0)    rectangle (1.2*\ws,\we+1); 
\fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0   ,gray!15] (-\ws,-1.2*\ws) rectangle (7,1.2*\ws); 
\draw[dashed] (0,0,\be) -- (0,0,0) -- (\ws,0,0)  node[midway,sloped, above, xshift=-0.65cm] {\SI{40}{cm}};
\fill[canvas is xy plane at z=0,gray!80] (\ws,0) circle (0.25) node[black,xshift=1.25cm] {}; %
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,cyan, dashed] (\ws,0) circle (2.25) node[black,xshift=0.85cm, align=left] {Boxing\\ Zone};


\draw[fill= red!20] ($(-135:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$) --++ (0,0,-9.6)
    {[canvas is xy plane at z=\be] arc (-135:45:\br)} -- ($(45:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$);

\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=\be+9.6,fill=red!40] (0,0) circle (\br);

\foreach[count=\xi]\i in{1.5,4.2,6.9}
{%                       1.5, 1.5+2.7, 1.5+2.7+2.7
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\be+\i] 
    \draw[orange] (0,0) circle (\br);
    \fill[orange] (0,0,\be+\i) circle (1pt); 
    \coordinate   (C\xi) at (225:\br+0.2); 
    %--
\foreach [evaluate={\kk={ifthenelse(\i<4, \k, \k+60)}}] \k in {0,120,240}    
    {       
      \begin{scope}[rotate=\kk]
        \draw[gray,dashed] (0,0) -- (\br,0);
        \draw[red, opacity=0.85, fill=blue!75,fill opacity=0.6,] (0.75,-0.12) rectangle (1.1,0.12);
      \end{scope}
    }
    %--
  \end{scope}
}

\foreach\i in {0,90,180,270}
{%
  \draw[line width=0.5mm] ($(\i:\br)+(0,0,\be+9.6)$) -- (0,0,\we-0.15);
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (0,-\br,\be+9.6) --++ (0,0,-0.5); 
\draw[line width=0.5mm] (\br, 0,\be+9.6) --++ (0,0,-0.5); 
% Wall structure
\begin{scope}[shift={(-\ws,0,\we)},line width=1.5mm]
  \draw (0.5*\ws ,0,0) -- (0,0,-0.5*\ws) -- (0,0,-\ws); 
  \draw (0,-0.5*\ws,0) -- (0,0.5*\ws,0); 
  \draw (0,0,0)        -- (1.25*\ws,0,0);
 
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```